When and how are the items in data.rel.ro section updated in Linux?
I'm refactoring a 32-bit application for 64-bit embedded Linux.
Currently there's huge amount of global settings which are defined as global variables, e.g. globalSetting_xxx in my application. The type of these variables is a struct like:
struct SettingItem {
    char* desc;
    void** ramPtr;
    unsigned value;
    ....;
};

All these variables are defined in one source file, e.g. setting.c, put to a user-defined segment SEGM_SETTING_STRUCT, and then compiled and linked to the main application statically.
In this case a tiny modification in setting.c can lead to a compilation of the whole app.
So I want to pack the setting.c as libsetting.so, then it's separated from the main application.
Now the problem I am facing is that the addresses of the globalSetting_xxx are wrong.
I checked the map file (main.map) of main application, and there's a section like this:
 *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*)
 .data.rel.ro   0x0000000080598410       0x20 d:/dev/toolchain/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/crt1.o
                0x0000000080598410                globalSetting_A
                0x0000000080598410                globalSetting_B
                0x0000000080598410                globalSetting_C
                0x0000000080598410                globalSetting_D
                0x0000000080598410                globalSetting_...

and in the map file (setting.map) of libsetting.so, there's a section:
 *(.SEGM_SETTING_STRUCT)
 .SEGM_SETTING_STRUCT
                0x00000000004f5f00   0x1bcec8 ./setting.o
                0x00000000004f5f00                globalSetting_A
                0x00000000004f5f38                globalSetting_B
                0x00000000004f5f70                globalSetting_C
                0x00000000004f5fa8                globalSetting_D
                0x00000000004f5fe0                globalSetting_....

I guess the 0x0000000080598410 in main.map is to be overwritten by dynamic loader during the loading phase?
I printed the starting address of SEGM_SETTING_STRUCT (I put a symbol just in front of SEGM_SETTING_STRUCT in the linker script for libsetting.so), it is something like 0xf70e5f00, but when I printed the address of &globalSetting_x, I got 0x80598410.
It seems the values (GOT? I guess.) in .data.rel.ro are not updated by loader.
Can anyone tell me the reason?

"In this case a tiny modification in setting.c can lead to a compilation of the whole app" - That's an ambiguous statement. How are the dependencies declared in the makefile? Isn't there a header file for the definition of those structures? Please explain why you think a shared library is going to solve this build problem of "a tiny modification".
